# Google Places does not return place in reach of radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am currently attempting to find place details for companies at specific addresses. For that, I encoded the address, which I have, into geo-coordinates using geopy. Then I use the google places API to fetch the surrounding places and use their id's to get details via google places details (find my code below).

The Problem is, that the company, which I can search for successfully on google maps, is not listed in the searchs results. One problem might be that the company is "permanently closed" - but as this is a field that is returned from Google Places, and I can still find the company via websearch on google maps, I think this shouldnt actually matter.

Do you have any idea why my place is not being among the returned ones?

My Code:

```
companies = [{'name': '"Bullermeck" Spielscheunen und Freizeitanlagen GmbH', 'address': 'Am Kirchplatz 6, 26441 Jever'}]
places = []
myfields = ['name', 'website', 'type', 'rating', 'review', 'url', 'formatted_address', 'permanently_closed']


for company in companies:
    placesForCompany = {'company': company['name'], 'original_address': company['address']}

    # Derive coordinates by converting the address with geopy
    location = geolocator.geocode(company['address'])
    coordinates = str(location.latitude) + ", " + str(location.longitude)
    placesForCompany['coordinates'] = coordinates

    # Search for places in a 500m radius - the radius is a bit higher because of the inaccuracy of geopy
    result = gmaps.places_nearby(location=coordinates, radius=500)

    # Gather the found places in this array
    placesForCompany['nearbyPlaces'] = []

    # Iterate all the found places
    for place in result['results']:
        # Use the place_id to get more information about the place from Google Place Details
        place_id = place['place_id']
        place_details = gmaps.place(place_id = place_id, fields = myfields, language='de')
        placesForCompany['nearbyPlaces'].append(place_details['result'])

    places.append(placesForCompany)
```

Here is a screenshot of my google maps search:
[image]

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/temporary-closures-now-available-places-api).

Comment: Btw if I search on Google Maps website for *"Bullermeck Spielscheunen und Freizeitanlagen GmbH"* the only result I get is *Bullermeck-Alfsee Spielscheunen und Freizeitanlagen GmbH, Barlager Str. 11, 49597 Rieste, Germany* which does **not** correspond to what you said in your question. Please clarify if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are searching for **Bullermeck Spielscheunen und Freizeitanlagen** at the address **Am Kirchpl. 6, 26441 Jever, Germany**. If you check this in [Geocoding API](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DBullermeck%2520Spielscheunen%2520und%2520Freizeitanlagen%252C%2520Jever), you'll get the place_id `ChIJZfmp_meJtkcR1D7UdD4Sex4`. Checking this place_id through a [Places Details request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJZfmp_meJtkcR1D7UdD4Sex4&key=YOUR_API_KEY), you'll see that this establishment's `business_status` is `CLOSED_PERMANENTLY`. Please do note that places tagged as **closed permanently/temporarily** are not searchable through Places Nearby Search as per this comment on a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153243032#comment5).

As you will notice on this [sample Nearby Search request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=53.57351%2C7.90154&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY), the API only returns places with "OPERATIONAL" business status and so your business which is tagged as permanently closed was not be returned in the search results.

**Note:** You need to add your own API key on the sample requests provided above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that did do the trick! That the Nearby Search requests didnt return places out of business was a vital information.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.